# converting va_list to variable argument?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function `log_message` it takes variable arguments.

```
log_message(int level, char *fmt, ...)
```

now before calling this(`log_message`) function i have to add new function(`_log_message`), and new function will call `log_message`.

```
_log_message(int level, char *fmt, ...)
```

new function is also same. when `_log_message` will call `log_message` it will convert variable input to `va_list`. Now i have `va_list`, i don't wanna change the original one, is there any way to change back to variable input, so i will able to call the original one(`log_message`).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to turn a `va_list` back into a list of arguments.

The usual approach is to define a base function which takes a `va_list` as an argument. For example, the standard C library defines `printf` and `vprintf`; the first is a varargs function and the second has exactly the same functionality but takes a `va_list` instead. Similarly, it defines `fprintf` and `vfprintf`. It's trivial to define `printf`, `vprintf`  and `fprintf` in terms of `vfprintf`:

```
int fprintf(FILE* stream, const char* format, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  int n = vfprintf(stream, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return n;
}

int vprintf(const char* format, va_list ap) {
  return vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
}

int printf(const char* format, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  int n = vprintf(format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return n;
}
```

(Similarly for the various `exec*` functions, which come in both `va_list` and `varargs` varieties.)

I'd suggest you adopt a similar strategy.

Comment: Why it's not possible? it looks like a Naive question but still i want to know.

Comment: It is not possible because there are no routines or syntax for handling  it.  c_decl requires the caller to push the items into the stack.  If it is a variable number, how does it know how many to push in?  At the end, the caller is responsible for unstacking - again, if it doesn't know how many there are, how will it know how many there are to unstack?

Comment: @Merom Simply because the standard defines no reliable way for doing so. The stack during the call looks completely different. Under usual platforms, `...` is passed successively on the stack, and `va_list` is a kind of pointer to such a succession of `...` arguments. And they simply provided no way to put them back onto the stack.